# How to separate one python list into 3 different lists according to the criteria

Tags: python, string, list, file-io, split

I have a python list like below:

```
A = ['"','<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky','<spec_token>' ,'(A)', 'red','<spec_token>', '(B)', 'blue', '<spec_token>','(C)', 'yellow','<eos>', '"']
```

For list `A`, what is the easiest way to do the followings?

- 1. remove ' " ' from the list, i.e.

```
A_new =  ['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky','<spec_token>' ,'(A)', 'red','<spec_token>', '(B)', 'blue', '<spec_token>','(C)', 'yellow','<eos>']
```

- 2. separate `A` into 3 lists, one for each multiple choice option, i.e. the output should be like below:

```
A_new_1 = ['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky','<spec_token>' ,'(A)', 'red']
A_new_2 = ['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky','<spec_token>' ,'(B)', 'blue']
A_new_3 = ['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky','<spec_token>' ,'(C)', 'yellow']
```

In my example, the ultimate goal is to get the lists `A_new_1`, `A_new_2` and `A_new_3`.

I am currently working on making python function to achieve this objective, and my code so far is the following:

```
# 2. for GPT2MCHeadModel (ARC, openbookQA)
def GPT2MCHeadModel_data_manipulator(file_path):
    f = open(file_path, "r") 
    ln = f.readline()
    ln = ln.replace('"', '') # remove unnecessary quotation marks from the raw text file.
    ln_split = ln.split()

    # insert appropriate tokens into the raw text files before processing them in GPT2MCHeads model.
    ln_split.insert(0, "<bos>") 
    ln_split.insert(len(ln_split) - 1, "<eos>") 
    ln_split.insert(ln_split.index("(A)"), "<mcOption>") 
    ln_split.insert(ln_split.index("(B)"), "<mcOption>") 
    ln_split.insert(ln_split.index("(C)"), "<mcOption>") 
    ln_split.insert(ln_split.index("(D)"), "<mcOption>")
```

and I am not sure how to separate the contents into 3 separate lists, one list for each multiple choice option.

Thank you,

Comment: Please show your effort

Comment: So what have you tried and what didnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
A = ['"','<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky','<spec_token>' ,'(A)', 'red','<spec_token>', '(B)', 'blue', '<spec_token>','(C)', 'yellow','<eos>', '"']

# Problem 1
A = [x for x in A if x != '"']

i = A.index("<spec_token>")
c = A.count("<spec_token>")

# Problem 2
output = [A[:i] + A[i+j*3:i+j*3+3] for j in range(c)]
```

**Output**

```
>>> A
['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky', '<spec_token>', '(A)', 'red', '<spec_token>', '(B)', 'blue', '<spec_token>', '(C)', 'yellow', '<eos>']
>>> output
[['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky', '<spec_token>', '(A)', 'red'],
 ['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky', '<spec_token>', '(B)', 'blue'],
 ['<bos>', 'What', 'colour', 'is', 'the', 'sky', '<spec_token>', '(C)', 'yellow']]
```